# Still have data in stderr, when I shouldn't have while executing command in shell

Tags: python, hadoop

I have this function that executes commands locally [1], but I invoke this command with the function `hdfs dfs -cat /user/xubuntu/digests/output1-1444497943/part-m-00000.digest`, I get the correct output in the `stdout`, and I get log4j data in the `stderr`. I can't find if the execution run successfully or not because of getting data in the `stderr`. If the execution ran successfully, why I get data in the `stderr`?

[1] Function to execute locally.
    def executeCommand(command):

```
  logging.debug("Executing: %s" % command)
  if "JAVA_HOME" not in os.environ:
    os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = JAVA_HOME

  logging.debug("command: %s" % command)

  try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = process.communicate()
    if len(err) > 0:  # there is an exception
        raise ValueError("Exception:\n" + err)
  except ValueError as e:
    return e.message
  return out
```

[2] output in stdout and stderr

```
output in stdout: '{"mapreduce.file.input.name":"hdfs:\\/\\/hadoop-coc-1:9000\\/input1\\/b.txt","mapreduce.file.output.name":"\\/output1-1444497943\\/part-m-00000","mapreduce.digest":"1b344587f6c1398e7aaa59cd5f01b585"}'

output in stderr: '15/10/10 15:25:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable\n'
```

Comment: Well, I tested with this line, and now the log4j and the correct output comes in the stdout. The only way to discard the logs is turning off logs in log4j? 

    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop logs all message at level **INFO** and above to the **console's stderr**.

As mentioned [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToConfigure):

Hadoop logs messages to **Log4j** by default. **Log4j** is configured via **log4j.properties** on the **classpath**. This file defines both what is logged and where. **For applications, the default root logger is "INFO,console", which logs all message at level INFO and above to the console's stderr**. Servers log to the "INFO,DRFA", which logs to a file that is rolled daily. Log files are named $HADOOP_LOG_DIR/hadoop-$HADOOP_IDENT_STRING-.log.